# Route url to php file with javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have researched this but found luck and my question really is a hope and I'm doubting this is possible.

Can you route URLs to a specific PHP file using JavaScript? Like you would with rewrites in .htaccess. It would be a lot easier for several reasons for me to just link a fake URL to a PHP file with JavaScript.

The scenario is that I am creating a user profiles with PHP, a database and jQuery. Since I am using a history API script I can easily provide a profile for users without editing the .htaccess file IF a user navigates to a profile with a link. To do this I would preventDefault on the link click so you don't get a 404, get the href value, use AJAX to get JSON data from a PHP file and then AJAX in the template with info loaded in.

The problem is when a user directly enters the URL for example www.example.com/joebloggs, this would just cause a 404 since that file does not exist. I would like to intercept the page load with jQuery and instead load up the PHP template and ajax in info with JSON.

If not possible I will use .htaccess it would just be easier to do it with JavaScript

Comment: Have you looked into hash routing? Eg: example.com/#joebloggs

Comment: Not possible. Or you will have to add javascrt in your 404 file, which is not elegant.

Comment: I should have said, I really do want to avoid using the # method. That's the reason I made a history API instead of the # routing method

Comment: When user enters url directly, browser reqests the page, on recieving the page browser runs javascrpt in it. There is no way to prevent getting 404page with js. But you can add your javascrpt to onload of your 404 template and show 404 message only if user really doesnt exist.

Comment: @sabithpocker seems I am going to just have to modify the .htaccess file since I really don't want to but js into the 404 page